# Event Runs many time when AllowRecursiveNodeChecking is true

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a problem when I use devexpress TreeListView with **AllowRecursiveNodeChecking** = True the event TreeListView1_OnNodeCheckStateChanged runs many times and I don't know how to do to run it only one time when CheckBox change :

My xaml :

```
<dxg:TreeListControl.View>
            <dxg:TreeListView CustomColumnDisplayText="CustomColumns"  ImageFieldName="LineIcon" ShowCheckboxes="True" AllowRecursiveNodeChecking="True" NodeCheckStateChanged="TreeListView1_OnNodeCheckStateChanged"  Name="TreeListView1" KeyFieldName="ID" ParentFieldName="ParentID" FontSize="13" NodeImageSize="16,16" ShowNodeImages="True" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Normal" />
</dxg:TreeListControl.View>
```

In My View :

```
    private void TreeListView1_OnNodeCheckStateChanged(object sender, TreeListNodeEventArgs e)
    {

        //My Code that run Many Times

    }
```

> I Know that I can handle this by Subscribe/Unsubscribe event but I don't know when to do It and AfterEvent does not exist for devexpress TreeListView

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Any idea to resolve this ?

Comment: No one to help me :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have done to avoid this problem :

```
       public bool ItemChecked = false;

       private void TreeListView1_OnNodeCheckStateChanged(object sender, TreeListNodeEventArgs e)
       {
          ItemChecked = true; 
          // To be sure that our code will run only if checkbox have changed
       }

       private void TreeListView1_OnNodeChanged(object sender, TreeListNodeChangedEventArgs e)
       {
          if (ItemChecked)
          {
           // My Code  
          }

         ItemChecked = false;
        }
```